# How to obfuscate JavaScript on the server side?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script I want to obfuscate or encrypt to hide from competition viewing the source code.  I have found simple JS obfuscators but the issue with my script is I have PHP echoing variables into the JavaScript.  The PHP is echoing strings and true/false.

Here is a piece of the JavaScript with PHP in it.

```
function redirect() {
    var r = <?php echo $rvar; ?>;
    if (r) {
        window.location = prepare("<?php echo $redirect; ?>");
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I can do to hide my JavaScript but be able to dynamically build the JS with PHP?

Comment: JavaScript is ALL clientside. There is literally nothing you can do to stop anyone accessing your site from seeing it. The browser has to know it to execute it, right? All this will do is make it harder for you to maintain it.

Comment: To hide your business logic, try putting more of it in server-side files, like php.

Comment: I know javascript is client side, but there has to be something where I can build the js script with php, then wrap that all up with some obfuscation then show that obfuscated js to the end user.

Comment: Sure, you can obfuscate it, but any developer can undo that. It'll just take time.  It doesn't matter how it's build before you obfuscate it. You simply cannot hide the logic in javascript.

Comment: I know obfuscating wouldnt be bullet proof.  What I am asking is how to obfuscate my php built javascript.  If this is something you know how to do it would greatly help me.

Comment: "competition viewing the source code" Is your JS really that valuable that people are going to copy and paste it? If it's an issue of protecting something other than the code, user server-side validation.

Comment: That's not only reason, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: If your competition has the incentive to "steal your javascript", it won't matter if you obfuscate it. It'll make them take maybe an hour of time to undo it. Obfuscating JS has very, very, very little purpose. Not even mentioning the problems that happen when the obfuscator messes up and your JS is broken. Do important stuff serverside and don't care about the JS

Comment: I understand.  That is one main reason but there are others.  I'm just looking for some help on my issue.  I am not looking to debate whether obfuscating has any value.

Comment: You might get close looking for a apache mod that minifies JS, etc. It'll come close to obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I have ever wanted to obfuscate code is when I have been utterly ashamed of it. Retrospectively, I would probably obfuscate everything I have ever written. If protecting source is integral to your well-being, consider a shift to desktop programming.

Nevertheless, if there is one thing experience and memory has afforded me, it is that any serious newcomer to this field will stubbornly move forward with their own ideas, regardless of how bad it is, how much it grinds against commonsense and best practice, or how much a thread poo-poos all over the question. If you keep at it, hindsight will generously remind you of this period--cringes and all; the chastisements of a few strangers will pale in comparison, so I will give you one possible answer.

Use PHP's [output buffering controls](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). You will want to start output buffering at the top of the script that will output all the JavaScript. This will capture everything into the buffer, which can then be assigned to a simple variable. This variable will contain everything that was supposed to be echoed out to the page immediately, but was instead captured and saved into the variable. This variable is just a regular string. Pass it to one of those JS obfuscators you found. This assumes it is done with PHP and is a PHP library for doing that. When it is obfuscated, echo it out. That is it. Here is an example:

```
<?php
// Start output buffering.
ob_start();

?>
function redirect() {
var r = <?php echo $rvar; ?>;
  if (r) {
    window.location = prepare("<?php echo $redirect; ?>");
  }
}
<?php

// Get all the output captured in the buffer, and turn off output buffering.
// This will be a string.
$js_source = ob_get_flush();

// Obfuscate the $js_source string, by passing it to the obfuscator
// library you found.
$obfuscated_js_source = obfuscator5000($js_source);

// Send the source code to the browser by echoing it out.
echo $obfuscated_js_source;
```